# Slide show/screensaver over login screen on RHEL 6.4

Tags: rhel, screensaver

I've see the slide show (Pictures folder) screensaver.  I've also seen how to change the background behind my login screen.  What I haven't been able to figure out is how to display a slide show as a screensaver over my login screen.  Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: If you're using GDM, I would reccomend switching to another DM that's easier to customize.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible looking at how GNOME3 and GDM currently work. At least not without having to restart /etc/init.d/gdm3 every time you want the image to rotate. This seems impractical.

The steps to change the login and the lock screen wallpaper are discussed here in this post titled: [Change desktop, login and lock screen wallpapers in GNOME 3.4](http://fabhax.com/technology/change-wallpapers-in-gnome-3.4/).

#### For example

I'll highlight the steps to change GDM's wallpaper just so you get a general idea of what I'm talking about.

**step 1 - become the gdm user**

```
su - gdm -s /bin/bash
```

**step 2 - change the image**

```
`dbus-launch | sed 's/^/export /'`
```

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file:///home/fabhax/wallpapers/NATURE-SkyStone_1920x1200.jpg

**step 3 - restart gdm3**

```
/etc/init.d/gdm3 restart
```

The steps are similar to do the same thing for the screen lock wallpaper. This could be scripted but it seems hackish.

Leave a comment if this is something you'd seriously like to have.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, link, and code example.  We already change our login wallpaper.   I really want to cover the login screen with a screensaver that will go away when the mouse or keyboard is touched like a normal screensaver.  I was hoping at logout there was a way to trigger the built in screen saver to go on.